# Qt & OpenGL OS X: GLSL shader version only 120 on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, qt, opengl, glsl, qt5

I'm trying to move some code from the fixed function OpenGL to GLSL shaders, by following along with the arcsynthesis tutorials. First I ran into the issue that version 330 isn't available which after a quick search seemed common, but the recommendation is that 150 should work fine. However, aside from 120 there's no other GLSL shader versions available, is this normal for a 2013 Macbook Air on 10.8.4? Or is there some weirdness going on with the combination of OpenGL + Qt 5 under OS X?

EDIT: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html if I build the sample app there I can use 140 and 150 (not tried 330 as it requires shader rewrites). Does anyone know if this is a specific issue related to OpenGL, Qt5 and OS X?

Comment: Make sure you're creating a Core context if you want to use `#version 150`.

Comment: Yeah, I just stumbled across that on another link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So:

```
QGLFormat glFormat;
glFormat.setVersion(3, 2);
glFormat.setProfile(QGLFormat::CoreProfile);

// Set the default GL format to OpenGL 3.2 Core
QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(glFormat);
```

That's what's needed for it to work, which is helpfully not obvious in the documentation. That'll give you 150. If you changed the `glFormat.setVersion(3, 2)` to 3, 3 it *seems* to give version 330 but I have no idea how reliable this will be until I've done some more work.

Comment: 3, 3 should give completely undefined results on OS X 10.8, since it only implements OpenGL 3.2 core. You do not actually need a core profile context to use GLSL 150 on most platforms, OS X is just extremely fussy - you either get 3.2 core or 2.1 and there is nothing in-between (in OS X 10.7/8 anyway).

Comment: Yeah I thought I'd get completely undefined results, turns out it works. Note, I have no idea about the portability of it off my Macbook Air or not, or whether I'll use a 3.3 specific function and it'll explode but the `location` part works perfectly. Highly weird!