# pyside qt4.8 os x core profile/3.2 compatibility (yes, I've read the other posts)

Tags: qt, opengl, pyside

No matter what I've tried, I cannot get a proper 3.2 context in pyside using qt 4.8. I have triple checked via the gl extensions manager, and my computer is certainly capable (100% of 4.1 core features).

"simple" version doesn't work...

```
f = QGLFormat()
f.setProfile(QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
f.setVersion(3,2)
QGLFormat.setDefaultFormat(f)
```

In fact, I cannot even successfully create a glcontext...

```
class GLView(QGLWidget):                                                                                                                                                         
  def __init__(self,name,parent=None):                                                                                                                                           
    QGLWidget.__init__(self,parent)                                                                                                                                              
    c = QGLContext(QGLFormat())                                                                                                                                                  
    logger.critical(c.create())  #returns False
```

This is after a QApplication exists and a MainWindow class is created and shown...

If I try to set the format on the built-in QGLWidget context, it fails as well --

```
self.context().setFormat(f)
self.context().makeCurrent()
```

"Cannot make invalid context current". Similarly does not work even if coreprofile is not specified, and version is set at 2.1.

Moving any of these to the initializeGL callback makes no difference.

I've looked at the following questions, which have not resolved my issue

- [PyQt4 OpenGL: Enabling OpenGL Core Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708478/pyqt4-opengl-enabling-opengl-core-profile) - solution was to move to qt5 (no official pyside release for this yet)
- [PyOpenGL cannot compile shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993306/pyopengl-cannot-compile-shader) - on debian, does not have same problem as os x
- [Getting OpenGL context newer than 2.1 with Qt 4 and Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971403/getting-opengl-context-newer-than-2-1-with-qt-4-and-mavericks) - unresolved
- [Qt & OpenGL OS X: GLSL shader version only 120 on Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277730/qt-opengl-os-x-glsl-shader-version-only-120-on-mountain-lion) - c++, same code does not work in pyside, as seen above

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
K

Comment: It would be helpful for those who might answer this question if you included a list of links to the other questions you've looked at that didn't help solve your problem (as your title implies)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708478/pyqt4-opengl-enabling-opengl-core-profile  -- solution was to move to qt5 (no official pyside release for this yet)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29993306/pyopengl-cannot-compile-shader  -- on debian, does not have same problem as os x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971403/getting-opengl-context-newer-than-2-1-with-qt-4-and-mavericks  -- unresolved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277730/qt-opengl-os-x-glsl-shader-version-only-120-on-mountain-lion  -- c++, same code does not work in pyside, as seen above

Comment: I realise you may want to stick with PySide for licensing reasons, but it could be worth trying both PyQt4 and PyQt5 to see if the issue persists. If it does not, you can try posting a bug to the PySide mailing list, but development seems pretty slow these days.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately licensing limited on this one, but indeed worth checking to see if the problem exists with PyQt as well -- will report back.

Comment: this post shows same problems with pyqt4. I have confirmed my same setup still does not work using pyqt4 in place of pyside. will investigate further.